# Upgraded to Phonegap3, project does not load needed plugins correctly

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

So I've tried posting some of these issues on the Phonegap forum but have not heard from anyone regarding my issues...

I recently upgraded from PG 2.9 to 3.3 and am having trouble adjusting my project to the change... it should be as easy as installing phonegap 3.3 and creating a new project and dragging my /www to the root of the project and calling the cordova CLI commands to build and update my project-- both of which say that they complete successfully.

But it's not that easy! Instead, building and updating my project deletes the cordova2.9.jar and does not create a 3.3.0 jar... so I build it myself which goes fine. I stick it in my /libs folder and my app loads on my phone finally... The problem now is that running in PG 3 requires a change in how API calls are handled-- they are all plugins which you have to install before using them... so I installed all of the needed plugins...

The problem now is this message in logcat within Eclipse:

```
Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/www/cordova/lib/cordova_plugins.js
```

so I find this cordova_plugins.js file in the root of my assets/www/ directory (Why is it here?! Shouldn't this be automated by cordova build & update to the correct location?!) So I try to copy the file to /www/cordova/lib/ where the error reports it is trying to find it.

When I do this, I get all of these errors:

```
Unable to open asset URL:file:///android_asset/www/cordova/lib/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/DirectoryEntry.js
Unable to open asset URL:file:///android_asset/www/cordova/lib/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/DirectoryReader.js
Unable to open asset URL:file:///android_asset/www/cordova/lib/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/File.js
Unable to open asset URL:file:///android_asset/www/cordova/lib/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/Entry.js
...etc (basically every plug-in that I had installed in the project.)
```

I am clearly missing something here... relocating these javascript files to the correct directory manually should not be what I need to do...

I should mention that this original error occurred when I was running the application in PG2.9 but the only plugins that I needed to use were included by default so I could still use the needed API functionalities.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 1):

You must need to create and deploy any phonegap project/application using Phonegap Command Line Interface

To Create any project write following command on command line:

```
$ phonegap create <path> <package_name> <project_name>
```

i.e.

```
$ phonegap create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

To add any platform to your project:

```
cd <path_to_project>
$ phonegap build <platform>
```

i.e.

```
cd hello
$ phonegap build ios
$ phonegap build android
```

To add any plugin feature to your project:

```
cd <path_to_project>
$ phonegap local plugin add <path_to_plugin>
```

i.e.

```
cd hello
$ phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git
```